# What is the meaning of ような on this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I am having problems trying to understand the meaning of ような on the next sentence:

> アリス：そう。みんなにすごく優しい子なんだから、勘違いしてしまうような男子がいそうで、心配だけどね。

My understanding is that ような means something like "similar to" or "like", but this type of correlation doesn't seem to translate very well to this case (at least literally).

This is how I would translate 勘違いしてしまうような男子がいそうで without understanding exactly the function of ような:

"Seems like there are boys who will misunderstand (unintentionally)"

Is ような fulfilling another function that I am not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ような sounds redundant to me. It’s like saying:

> 勘違いしてしまう**ような**男子がいそうで
> It seems there are boys **like those** who will mistakenly think she likes them

Without it, the meaning basically remains the same.

> 勘違いしてしまう男子がいそうで
> It seems there are boys who will mistakenly think she likes them

Answer (score 1):

According to デジタル大辞泉 entry on ようだ,

> （２）**例示**の意を表す。「隣のおばさんのような働き者は少ない」

The ような in「勘違いしてしまうような男子」simply illustrate what type of 男子 is.

If it helps, here's my tentative translation of the sentence you provided

> Alice: Yeah. Since she is very nice to everyone, it seems to me there are **guys like the ones who take it as a wrong idea**. I'm worried about that.